# Как создать список независимых объектов класса, содержащих списки?

Tags: python, ооп, list

Несмотря на то что я использую copy.deepcopy() при записи объекта в результирующий массив, массив объекта все равно меняется во всем списке, как отвязать объекты друг от друга?

```py
import copy


class test:
    arr = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.arr.clear()


arr0 = []
for i in range(10):
    m = test()
    for j in range(10):
        m.arr.append(i + j)
    arr0.append(copy.deepcopy(m))
```

вот вывод

```py
for elem in arr0:
    print(elem.arr)
```

```bash
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = []


arr0 = []
for i in range(10):
    m = T()
    for j in range(10):
        m.arr.append(i + j)
    arr0.append(m)
```